# create file share in azure using az cli

Tags: azure, azcopy, az

I want to create a file share in azure storage account using command line .

i am using the command `az storage share create --name myfile --account-name $NAME --account-key $key` . but it is showing an error.

I also tried azcopy make "url for file share?accountkey"
but it is also not working .i am using azcopy version 7.3

this is the error which i am getting.

The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='redboxtfstatebedtqgliqc.file.core.windows.net',
>   port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /myfile?restype=share
>   (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
>   'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify
>   failed')],)",),))

Comment: Try to update the Azure CLI latest version? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: i am using latest azure cli

Comment: Could you run the `az storage share` in Azure cloud shell? It seems to be related to an SSL cert issue.

Comment: but i want to do it with my cmd not Azure cloud shell....any suggestions

Comment: When did the error happen?`I also tried azcopy make "url for file share?accountkey" ` what do you mean?

Comment: the mentioned error is of "az storage share create --name myfile --account-name $NAME --account-key $key".  when i run azcopy make "url for file share?accountkey" i get " The syntax of the command is incorrect. Error parsing the argument "make": parameter name is required".

Comment: Not clearly. Which command do you run to get the error? `az storage share create` or `azcopy`?

Comment: az storage share create

Comment: Also, check if your local firewall or corporate firewall intercepting one REST API call. refer to [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/9355). and can you run `telnet redboxtfstatebedtqgliqc.file.core.windows.net 443` to verify this? I also suggest reinstalling your azure cli.

Comment: I believe you're getting this error is because there's a self-signed certificate somewhere in your certificate chain (may be a proxy server), that is decrypting the request and then signing it again. Just do a search for `tls_process_server_certificate` and you'll see lots of threads with this issue.

Comment: If proxy uses self-signed certificates, you could refer to these ways in the wiki:https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/doc/use_cli_effectively.md#working-behind-a-proxy

Comment: well i adapted a different method for what i wanted to do ...so now file share creation is not the part of it .thanks for all of your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem like the author of the post. It can be solved following the link which George Chen posted:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/doc/use_cli_effectively.md#working-behind-a-proxy

1. You need to edit the file: "C:\path_to_your_cli_installation\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem" and add the certificate of your proxy server
2. You need to set the environment variable REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE to "C:\path_to_your_cli_installation\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem"